# Chopped .css file in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, asset-pipeline, unicorn

### I getting lopped (chopped) application.css file in production mode (*only in browser*, both in Chrome and Firefox).

```
http://198.211.125.210/
```

[image: Chopped .css]

### But the direct link shows the full compiled application.css file.

```
http://198.211.125.210/assets/application-371482c69e94141a6e3eedd72a8a066f.css
```

### Why browser doesn't show full applcation.css file?

I use Nginx(1.2.7)+Unicorn(4.6.2)+Rails(3.2.12)+Capistrano(2.14.2).
My configuration:
[nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5129883)
[unicorn.rb](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5129905)
[deploy.rb](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5129912)
[Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5129961)
There's no errors in [production.log](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5129936)
[nginx.error.log](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5129942)
[$> cap deploy](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5130016)
[application.css (development)](https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/5133415)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you add the original CSS file that contains the code that is being chopped.

Comment: I use https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass (I added application.css in bottom of my config list)

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "I added application.css in bottom of my config list"  add your application.css to the question and any other css files that you have added CSS code to.

Comment: As I think I did wrong @import of bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by server reinstall.